# Getting this after uninstalling java

Tags: java, ubuntu, installation, javac, uninstallation

Getting this after uninstalling java

```
java -version
bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

And when I check for javac I get this

```
javac -version
bash: /usr/bin/javac: No such file or directory
```

Instead I expect this

```
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-5-jre-headless
 * openjdk-8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.9-jre-headless
 * openjdk-9-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt-get install <select package>
```

To output
Please help me.

Comment: How exactly did you uninstall Java? Can you please share your PATH environment variable. Also share output of `alias | grep java`, because it seems like command java is looking at that particular path where it doesn't exist.

Comment: I tried alias | grep java, it works magically. Can you tell me how did that happen please @CodeTalker

Comment: bash still knows where the commands *were*, logout and back in. Or login to a different (virtual) terminal. `ssh localhost` should do in a pinch.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yeah I guess it worked when I opened terminal again and checked it gave me the output as desired can you explain me why that happened?

Comment: Take a look at the [`command-not-found`](https://askubuntu.com/a/821638/214223) package for the details. But I believe it has to do with exactly how that is integrated with `bash`. The environment having had java but then having it removed is exactly the kind of situation that can cause an event to no longer fire.

Answer (score 1):

Bash had an `alias` set as `java` and alias was set to `usr/bin/java`. When you have any alias set, bash expands the alias and executes it. Here your alias `usr/bin/java` did not exist as you uninstalled java hence it says `No such file or directory`.
Remove the alias or restart shell and you will get the desired message.
Same applies to `javac`.

Read more about `alias` [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html).